Is it possible to use a node.js library such as fingerprint-generator from within a Chrome extension background script?
As the title really.
I'm making a request from within the background script of a Chrome extension that requires use of a fingerprint-generator - specifically headers as I'm going via a rotating proxy service.
I had built this in node.js originally, but want to migrate the code into the extension for performance purposes.
Is there a way to do this, to include the required libraries, or is there an alternative simpler library I can use as I think fingerprint-generator is more than I need for headers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
